# Deploy with docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Not sure if it will be a duplicate question but i tried to find out stuff but not sure if i have similar situation like others.
So i am new to docker and trying to setup a deployment for a small website.

So far i have a folder which has 3 files.

> 1. index.html - has basic html
> 2. Dockerfile - which has

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

> 3. docker-compose.yml - which has

```
version: '2.1'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        image: myname/myapp:1.0.0
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
            - ./host-volumes:/cont-volumes
        network_mode: "host"
    phpfpm56:
        image: php-fpm:5.6
        container_name: phpfpm56
        volumes:
            - ./host-volumes:/cont-volumes
        network_mode: "host"
    mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: mysql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
        volumes:
            - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
    mysql:
```

Now i am using jenkins to create build, putting my all codes to host volumes to make it available to container and then i would run

```
docker-compose build
```

Now it creates an image and i push it to `docker hub`.

**Then i login to remote server and pull the image and run. But that wont work because i still need to run docker-compose up inside the container.**

Is this the right approach or i am missing something here?

Comment: Do you just want to run the image in the remote server? Or run the image as the docker compose?

Comment: Well i can just run the image but that wont do anything. right? Because it has nothing except a index.html, a Dokcerfile and a docker-compose.yml. So until and unless i run docker-compose up its of no use. - This is my thought BTW. Also if i want to run docker-compose i need to run the image first then login to that container and then run dockerc-compose. Do you think the whole setup is correct or i should follow a different approach.

Comment: If the index.html file will use the other things like in the docker compose, you cannot just run the new image in the remote server only.

Comment: No right, docker compose just help you set the link for your images. So run the dokcer-compose inside the container is not right.

Comment: So what should i be doing? Like use Dockerfile to create an image and run it. No docker-compose. OR no need to create image rather just copy the whole code to server and then run docker-compose. No Dockerfile.

Comment: Keep your compose file outside the project folder. Create a build and push to docker hub. Then move compose file to the host machine, where you want run the image. Then finally use `docker-compose up` command to run the docker image

Comment: If you just want to run the new image and something needed in other images. The [multiple stages for docker image build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) are helpful. When the image is created well, then you can run it anywhere.

Comment: @SameerK this can be done. Seems a viable option. In that case i will have a Dockerfile in the project folder which will copy my whole code to an image. I will push it to hub. Pull it. Run it. And then run compose up. Then how do i connect those together?

Comment: In the compose file, you need add `image` key and point it to the image with proper tag that you pushed to docker hub,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to **copy your code into the image**.  Do not bind-mount host folders containing your code; instead, use a Dockerfile `COPY` directive to copy in the application code (and in a compiled language, use a `RUN` command to build it).  For example, your PHP container might have a corresponding Dockerfile that looks like (referencing [this base Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/545a73c9704c5f74b79f4373ffa02776159079a5/7.3/stretch/fpm/Dockerfile))

```
FROM php-fpm:5.6
# Base Dockerfile defines a sensible WORKDIR
COPY . .
# Base Dockerfile sets EXPOSE 9000
# Base Dockerfile defines ENTRYPOINT, CMD
```

Then your `docker-compose.yml` would say, in part

```
version: '3'
service:
  phpfpm56:
    build: .
    image: me/phpfpm56:2019-04-30
    # No other settings
```

And then your nginx configuration would say, in part (using the Docker Compose service name as a hostname)

```
fastcgi_pass phpfpm56:9000
```

If you use this in production you need to comment out the `build:` lines I think.

If you're extremely set on a workflow where there is no hostname other than `localhost` and you do not need to rebuild Docker images to update code, you at least need to restart (some of) your containers after you've done the code push.

```
docker-compose stop app phpfpm56
docker-compose up -d
```

You might look into a system-automation tool like Ansible or Chef to automate the code-push mechanism.  Those same tools can also just install nginx and PHP, and if you're trying to avoid the Docker image build sequence, you might have a simpler installation and deployment system running servers directly on the host.

Comment: But in this case my nginx wont be able to see files if i dont mount/bind volumes. And that will lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

docker-compose up should not be run inside a container but on a docker host. So this could be run via sh on a host but you need to have access to the composefile wherever you run the command.